# Sub Select using different where coluimns

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a table and I want

1. the **sum** of column 1 (just an example) if column 2 has a data
2. the **average** of column 1 (just an example again) if columns 2 is empty
3. it to be grouped by name and have the computation reflect per user

So I have 2 different computations for column 1 and the computation is based on whether column 2 has a data or NULL.

I was able to get the SUM but not the average.

```
SELECT T1.user_name, T1.Good_Hours, T2,*
(
   SELECT user_name, SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( total_tat ) ) ) as Good_Hours
   FROM Table 1
   WHERE etc_type = "YES"
   WHERE date_time BETWEEN "(DATETIME example Only)" AND "(DATETIME example Only)"
   AND column2 IS NULL
   GROUP BY user_name
) as T1,
(
   SELECT COUNT(column2) , SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(total_tat))) as NICE_TIME
   FROM Table 1
   WHERE etc_type = "YES"
   WHERE date_time BETWEEN "(DATETIME example Only)" AND "(DATETIME example Only)"
   AND column2 IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY user_name
) as T2
```

I got the `Good_Hours` but the second subselect returns the first record only and repeats it for the entire table.

What am I missing?

What I want:

```
user_name   -  missed_calls   - Good_Hours - NICE_TIME
John Doe           0             00:01:00    08:00:00
Jane Doe           5             00:14:00    29:00:00
Hugo Doe           9             00:47:00    00:10:00
```

What I get:

```
user_name   -  missed_calls   - Good_Hours - NICE_TIME
John Doe           0             00:01:00    08:00:00
Jane Doe           5             00:14:00    08:00:00
Hugo Doe           9             00:47:00    08:00:00
```

RAW data then desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use conditional aggregation here.  Assuming the ranges in the `WHERE` clauses be the same:

```sql
SELECT
    user_name,
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN column2 IS NULL THEN TIME_TO_SEC(total_tat) ELSE 0 END)) AS Good_Hours,
    SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(CASE WHEN column2 IS NOT NULL THEN TIME_TO_SEC(total_tat) END)) AS NICE_TIME
FROM Table1
WHERE etc_type = 'YES' AND
      date_time BETWEEN ? AND ?
GROUP BY user_name;
```

This approach makes a single pass over the table and computes the sum or average based on the value of `column2`.

Comment: It was great. I just removed "column2 IS NULL" in the WHERE section.......Thanks a lot